# ACTION PICK of photo from SD filtering for size or resolution?

Tags: android, android-intent, action, photo, picker

I'm getting a photo from sd starting a new intent how this:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

This work great! but in some cases, image size is too large and mobile device crashes. If is a normal size image not problem, but I wanna a way to filter or avoid the larger size images.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 0);
```

hope it will help, it works for me.

Comment: Thanks but this dont fix my problem. With this intent allow open larger size images yet :S I dont found nothing about filter or hide larger images with these methods u_u. I really thanks you

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this problem, I use the next method to get the bitmap resized using Bitmaps options. You can set the max size (actually 1.2MP) but it's great result there.

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String path) {

Uri uri = getImageUri(path);
InputStream in = null;
try {
    final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1200000; // 1.2MP
    in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);

    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
    in.close();



    int scale = 1;
    while ((o.outWidth * o.outHeight) * (1 / Math.pow(scale, 2)) > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
        scale++;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "scale = " + scale + ", orig-width: " + o.outWidth       + ", orig-height: " + o.outHeight);

    Bitmap b = null;
    in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
    if (scale > 1) {
        scale--;
        // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
        // larger than target
        o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inSampleSize = scale;
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);

        // resize to desired dimensions
        int height = b.getHeight();
        int width = b.getWidth();
        Log.d(TAG, "1th scale operation dimenions - width: " + width    + ", height: " + height);

        double y = Math.sqrt(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                / (((double) width) / height));
        double x = (y / height) * width;

        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) x,     (int) y, true);
        b.recycle();
        b = scaledBitmap;

        System.gc();
    } else {
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    }
    in.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "bitmap size - width: " +b.getWidth() + ", height: " + b.getHeight());
    return b;
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(),e);
    return null;
}
```

}